# Is there a way I can categorize a java application as a game?

Tags: java, game-development

Some details are going to be extraneous, however I'm going to include them for as much detail as possible, as I am not entirely sure how to ask this. I was playing around with my graphics driver and noticed that it had been storing metrics for different games I've played on the system. This got me thinking "how does AMD know these are games?" I noticed all the games that were listed were either from my Steam library or actual Microsoft games (like Minecraft Bedrock Edition). I have been writing my own game* completely from scratch and this got me wondering if there was some kind of flag or I could write into the program that will tell the OS or other systems that might be looking that it is a game.

- - Yes I understand "reinventing the wheel" is a long and ultimately useless endeavor, as my "wheel" will never be as good as what society has already been working on. However this is a passion project just to see if I **can**. I have no plans of releasing it in any way as it's just a learning tool and I am enjoying doing it, so please spare me the lecture.

I tried Googling but "Java how do I tell windows program is a game" isn't a very good query and I couldn't really think of another way to ask, so this is my next step. I was hoping there'd be something simple like a flag, but learning new things is exactly why I am doing this from scratch.

Comment: id go to the source: "display driver X game metrics API" and such like

Comment: I have literally no idea of how it works, and I didn't even know that metrics were collected for games. However, I may suppose it's related to how applications are signed. You can check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/authenticode-signing-for-game-developers) out

Comment: https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amd-catalyst-recognising-javaw-exe-as-jedi-academy/td-p/396804

Comment: IMO the system can tell automatically it is a 'game' based on the types of instructions performed or library that will utilize the GPU used in the application. The instructions for GPU will be passed automatically from CPU to GPU to handle.